# Failed to access dependency implemented in Android/Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, github, jitpack, jetpack

I published my own library on Jetpack Compose using Jitpack. When I create a sample project and implement the dependency to test the library, there is no problem and the project compiles successfully. However, when I try to access the custom view, there is no import. Can you help me with this?

To solve the problem, I downgraded the java version from 17 to 11, but this time I got a compilation error via jitpack. Even though I also updated the jitpack.yml file.

My library on GitHub: [Click](https://github.com/furkanayaz/Slippy-Bottom-Bar)
My library on Jitpack: [Click](https://jitpack.io/#furkanayaz/Slippy-Bottom-Bar)

Comment: By the way, sample code is available in my github repo :)

Comment: I solved the problem. If you will release your library as "minifyEnabled = true" in build.gradle (library-module) then you will encounter this problem. I changed as "false" in setting property. And fixed the problem :)